# Using number keys as meta keys in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm learning emacs and am trying to implement my standard keyboard shortcuts. Currently I use the number keys as meta keys, for instance I hold 4 and press N to highlight the previous word, but if I press and release 4 alone then the number 4 is entered into the text buffer.

Is it possible to implement this behavior in emacs? It would be great if I could just do

```
(global-set-key (kbd "4-N") 'highlight_left)
```

Comment: I doubt that there is any reasonably simple way to achieve this. Sorry. :-(

Comment: Interesting idea. Did you learn it from somewhere, or is it original to you?

Comment: It's original to me. I use it on Windows at the moment, via a Python script I call PinkyTwirl (not part of emacs). You can check it out at https://github.com/JordanFisher/PinkyTwirl

Answer (score 0):

[Key-chord](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyChord) may be what you want.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good start. I'll see if I can modify Key-chord so that there can be a long delay between pressing the first key and the second, and also so that if the first key is released before the second key then the chord is canceled.

Answer (score 0):

You can get something similar easily: Define `4` as a prefix key, with `4 4` to insert `4` and `4 N` to highlight etc. (No, it's not the same thing -- here you don't hold `4` down while hitting `N` etc.)